# Golang file renaming

Tags: go, filenames

Since yesterday I was trying to write a script/program that would change filenames. Alongside learning golang I also started to make animations and for some reason Illustrator names every .png file I make like this - "name_working space 1 copy.png" and "* copy (number).png". I was tired of renaming those files manually and today I found this code and modified 1 line of it to get rid of "_working space 1 copy" but only from those files that have numbers. That leaves me with 2 files that are first frames of my animations and those are - "name_working space 1.png"; "name_working space 1 copy.png". I could totaly live with it by leaving those 2 blank but since I try to learn golang I wanted to ask if I can improve it to replace every single filename. I started learning monday this week.

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "regexp"
)

func currentDir() {
    dir := "D:\\GoLang\\src\\gocourse\\renamefile\\rename"
    file, err := os.Open(dir)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed using this directory %s", err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    list, err := file.Readdirnames(0)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed reading directory: %s", err)
    }

    re := regexp.MustCompile("_working space 1 copy ")
    for _, name := range list {
        oldName := name
        fmt.Println("Old name - ", oldName)
        newName := re.ReplaceAllString(oldName, "$1")
        fmt.Println("New Name - ", newName)
        err := os.Rename(filepath.Join(dir, oldName), filepath.Join(dir, newName))
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("error renaming file: %s", err)
            continue
        }
        fmt.Println("File names have been changed")
    }
}

func main() {
    currentDir()
}
```

- ball_working space 1.png --> ball-1.png;
- ball_working space 1 copy.png --> ball-2.png;
- ball_working space 1 copy 1.png --> ball-3.png;
- ball_working space 1 copy 2.png --> ball-4.png etc.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a reimplementation of your code. However it is not complete, as you need
to better clarify what the names look like before, and what they should look like
after.

```
package main

import (
   "os"
   "path/filepath"
   "strings"
)

func main() {
   dir := `D:\GoLang\src\gocourse\renamefile\rename`
   list, err := os.ReadDir(dir)
   if err != nil {
      panic(err)
   }
   for _, each := range list {
      name := each.Name()
      newName := strings.ReplaceAll(name, "_working space 1 copy", "")
      os.Rename(filepath.Join(dir, name), filepath.Join(dir, newName))
   }
}
```

Comment: name_working space 1 copy 1.png - ... - name_working space 1 copy 65.png and two files that have names(first 2 frames of animation): "name_working space 1 copy.png" and "name_working space 1.png" and I want them to look like this "name-#.png" (# - numbers from 1 to 67 for example). I can name it like this "ball-_working space 1.png" so all I need is to get rid of "_working space 1 copy" and "_working space 1" or replace it with proper numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could just parse the first part of each file name until it encounters an underscore. A function to illustrate if you are sure that the file you want to extract always ends with the same symbol '_'.

```
fileNames := []string{"ball_working space 1.png", "ball_working space 1 copy.png",
"ball_working space 1 copy 1.png", "ball_working space 1 copy 2.png"}

func parseName(names []string) {
    res := []string{""}
    for ind, val := range names {
        data := val[:strings.IndexByte(val, '_')] // reads until the hardcoded symbol
        data += "-" + strconv.Itoa(ind)
        res = append(res, data)
    return res
}
```

Then you will have a slice with all the "correct" file names and you can unpack it in your way of preference.